# How do I clear the contents of this List which is created on the fly?

Tags: c#, list, xamarin

I'm sure this is a simple question but I'm having trouble clearing out all of the contents of a List object that is being created on the fly. In the past I have instantiated a List and worked with it in the normal ways and then when I need to clear it I just use the

```
myList.Clear();
```

and that works fine.

In this case however I'm using a different approach to grab some data and format it into a List quickly and it works fine.

Here is the code:

```
var dailyPrices = $"https://www.myURL.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol={symbol}&apikey={apiKey}&datatype=csv".GetStringFromUrl().FromCsv<List<MyStockData>>();
```

My problem is that dailyPrices is created on the fly using ServiceStack.
If I add:

```
dailyPrices.Clear();
```

AFTER the first line it works fine, but of course clears out everything that was just put in there. If I use the Clear command above the line it is not recognized because dailyPrices does not exist yet.

How can I overcome this? Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that we can copy, compile, and run ourselves that illustrates what you are trying to do.

Comment: Also describe more clearly what you are trying to do? In particular, when do you want to clear the list? I don't think you want to clear it immediately after you get a response from the API. You need to think more about exactly what action the user takes that will cause the list to clear?

Comment: _"AFTER the first line it works fine, but of course clears out everything that was just put in there"_ -- if that's a problem, then why are you trying to clear the list at all? You can't reference `dailyPrices` before your statement, because the variable hasn't been declared yet. But since it hasn't been declared yet, never mind initialized, there's nothing there to clear. So, what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Bottom line here: you have not provided sufficient detail for us to understand your question. I find it very likely that it's an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and that clearing the list isn't actually required at all. But without more context, it's impossible to say for sure. Please improve the question, including providing a good [mcve] that shows clearly what is going on; it is not possible to provide a good answer as it stands now.

Answer (score -1):

OK I solved the problem after a little investigating, and embarrassingly, it had nothing to do with the List or clearing it at all. I can clear the List AFTER the chart has been drawn.

I'm using Syncfusion charts to illustrate everything. When I refresh the chart and retrieve new data for a new stock, certain visual elements of the chart get redrawn, but some other visual elements do not and remain. Coincidentally those elements that remain and get altered related to the List in question.

However, they can be manually removed with the following code:

```
myChart.ChartAnnotations.Clear();
```

So if I simply Clear out all of the SyncFusion chart elements each time the chart is ready to be redrawn, it all looks as expected when new data is loaded.

Comment: I'm glad you solved it. If you had actually asked THIS question, instead of the one that you did, we probably could have done more to help you.  Like Peter suggested above, this is a great example of an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)